# How to pass config as command line argument in Pytest which is not used as test input

Tags: command, arguments, line, pytest

Want to know how do I read the command line argument for "Pytest" to get the input and use the variable not as test input with fixture but a parameter to do some other operation.
Here is what I am trying to achieve :

```
pytest --folder=< label > test_my_logic.py
```

where label can be a, b and c.and based on the label value I will get the  actual 'folder' path which has expected data. e.g.

- label=a, folder=common/test_data/a
- label=b, folder=common/test_data/b

### I have added the conftest.py as below:

```
import pytest

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--folder", action="store", default="All",
        help="Please enter the folder which needs to be executed")

@pytest.fixture
def folder(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--folder")
```

---

I have a json and util method using which I can read the json to get the value of actual folder value of a,b etc. I am seeking help to know  in my script how do I get the  argument --folder and use it to do other operation instead of passing it to the test method with fixture in my script ? In my test script where I am reading various global variables , I have :

### test_my_logic.py

```
import pytest
import json
import sys


sys.path.append(os.path.realpath("%s/../../../../../common/utils" % os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
import utils


print folder
TEST_ATTRIB = utils.getTestAttributes()['LOL']
PLACE_REQUEST_URL  = utils.getURLs()['IMO']
...
...
```

---

### In command line:

```
py.test --folder=a tests/test_my_logic.py
```

### Error returned:

```
tests/test_my_logic.py:16: in <module>
    print folder
E   NameError: name 'folder' is not defined
```

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 1):

`folder` is a fixture, it should be used as a parameter for test:

```
def test_a(folder):
    print folder
```